# use objectdetection model predict the image subscribed by kinect topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the tensorflow object detection API train a model, I want to use the image topic in the kinect camera and identify it with the trained model. I found that recognition is much less effective than using image recognition directly. Why is that? Is it caused by predicting the image in rosimage format after converting it to cv::mat? Is there any way to solve it?

```
image_topic = "/kinect2/qhd/image_color"

self._cv_bridge = CvBridge()

self._sub = rospy.Subscriber(image_topic, Image, self.mycallback, queue_size=1) 

def mycallback(self,image):
  
    cv_image = self._cv_bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_msg, "bgr8")
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv_image)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326626/use-objectdetection-model-predict-the-image-subscribed-by-kinect-topic/) by [ffzj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41923/ffzj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem, bgr8 is not the suitable type foe the model ,i have changed the cv_image type to rgb8.

---

Originally posted by [ffzj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41923/ffzj/) with karma: 28 on 2019-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0